# Stuck in infinite loop with the log: Background partial/sticky concurrent mark sweep GC

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, leakcanary

I am creating an app (that will **not** be in the play store) that uses a lot of memory with Webview, and by using LeakCanary I have found a fixed a several small memory leaks. There are 2 leaks that are much harder to fix than the rest but are also much smaller than any others (10-12kb leaked every couple of hours) and I have had to leave them in for the time being. After letting my app run over night I usually come back to a flood of logs like so:

> Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 263432(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 44MB/60MB, paused 13.441ms total 226.525ms
>
> Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 145187(13MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 46MB/60MB, paused 12.864ms total 164.097ms
>
> Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 265421(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 44MB/60MB, paused 13.632ms total 230.849ms
>
> Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 147514(14MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 46MB/60MB, paused 13.037ms total 167.625ms

These logs repeat, one every 2 seconds, endlessly and cause the app to freeze until I kill the app and start over.

In my manifest I have added

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

And because my app needs to run continuously (essentially forever) I have implemented an alarm for 1 AM every morning to kill the app and restart with a clean environment. This is not a best practice but it does act as a nice catchall for any bugs that occur due to the unusually long life of the app.

Can one or two small memory leaks really cause this much damage? What else could be causing these logs to repeat so much? How can I fix it?

Comment: ever get an answer for this?

Comment: Nope. And it is still happening

Answer (score 1):

I think those logs are there because of Leak Canary implementation. Disable Leak Canary and you won't see those logs anymore.